# how to skip "is this a single-disk" archive message

Tags: shell-script, zip

after running this code terminal asks me "is this a single-disk archive : y/n". where I need to type y and press enter but I want to do this from the code I am running. In other words I don't want to manually press y and then enter key.

````
mkdir fireDataSet1
cd fireDataSet1
cp  '/content/fire_dataset/fire image dataset2/fire image dataset.z80' dataset.zip
zip -r -FF dataset.zip --out dataset.zip.fixed
unzip dataset.zip.fixed```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yes | unzip dataset.zip.fixed
```

Comment: ```yes | unzip dataset.zip.fixed``` results same. It still requires to type y and enter.